# Dynamically change what cloud function I use base on environment (prod or testing)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been working on a website using React.JS and Firebase for a couple of months now. As we are nearing launch time, I wanted to separate the production and testing environments. I have been able to do this by following this [guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html) from Firebase. This basically tells you to just create two Firebase projects and switch back and forth as needed.

This works rather nicely for everything but the Cloud Functions. Right now I am calling the Cloud functions as follows:

```
const { output: data } = await axios.post("https://region-project.cloudfunctions.net/cloudFunction", {
    input: data
  });
```

Where the URL is static. My goal would be to be able to run the code without manually having to change this URL. I think there are two possibilities:

1. Change the URL when I run `firebase use test` or `firebase use prod`
2. Change the URL when I run `npm start` and `npm build`

I think the second one is most feasible, as I have seen online that you can add a `--configuration` to both those scripts.

If this is possible, how would I go about implementing such a thing? Would I need to create my own npm script?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that code you're showing on the client or server?  What is actually invoking the function that needs to be configured?

Comment: I am not too confident on the terminology, so I apologize if this does not make sense. That code snipet runs when the user of my website clicks a button, which I believe means its on the client. I am not trying to configure the Cloud Function itself, but rather dynamically change which function I am calling. If I am in production, I want to run the production function. The same for testing.

Comment: If you are trying to invoke the function from your web client, you should look into the configuration of that app code, and not Firebase products.  It's pretty easy to see how to modify that URL based on what project you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client-side (the React/javascript code that runs in the user's browser), you need to do two things.

First, initialize firebase to target the appropriate Firebase project, either by using the [init.js script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-hosting-urls), or by calling [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn) with the specific config.

Then, you can access the project id through the initialized app, and use it to configure the Functions URL:

```
const projectId = firebase.app().options.projectId;
const region = "europe-west3";
const functionsUrl = `https://${region}-${projectId}.cloudfunctions.net`;
```

Finally you can use axios to trigger your Functions this way:

```
const output = await axios.post(`${functionsUrl}/cloudFunction`, { input });
```